# FDA with R: How to get max() of curve in fda-object?

Tags: r, max, data-analysis

I have some functional data as fda-object. Now I got the first derivative and want to have the coordinates of the maximum value of each single curve. How is this possible?

For better understanding I include some fictional data I took from [here](https://rviews.rstudio.com/2021/10/14/fda-and-the-dynamics-of-curves/):

```
library(fdaoutlier);
library(fda);

set.seed(95139);
n_obs <- 50;
n_curves <- 100
mod4 <- simulation_model4(n = n_curves, p = n_obs, outlier_rate = .5, seed = 50, plot = FALSE)
index1 <- mod4$true_outliers;
curves_mat <- mod4$data;

n_order   = 4;
knots    = c(seq(0,n_obs,5))
n_basis   = length(knots) + n_order - 2;
 

spline_basis = create.bspline.basis(rangeval = c(0,n_obs), nbasis = n_basis, norder = n_order)
df1 <- curves_mat[index1,] 
df1_obj <- Data2fd(argvals = 1:n_obs, y = t(df1), basisobj = spline_basis, lambda = 0.5)
```

So, how can I get the coordinates of the maximum value of each single curve of `df1_obj`?

Answer (score 0):

Some kind of workaround, maybe somebody can add a better solution:
`eval.fd()` gives a discrete representation of the curves, and so one can get a maximum of them.

```
fine_df1 <- eval.fd(seq(0,50,length=500),df1_obj);
max_df1 <- array(NA,2);
for(c in c(1:dim(fine_df1)[2])){
    cur <- fine_df1[,c];
    m <- max(cur); 
    i <- which(cur %in% m); 
    max_df1 <- rbind(max_df1, c(i,m));
}
max_df1 <- max_df1[2:dim(max_df1)[1],];
plot(max_df1);
```